# Gmail api client library cannot send email java

Tags: java, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to send an email using java client api. No matter what I try, I get this json error:

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "message": "Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied",
            "reason": "forbidden"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied"
}
```

Any ideas how to bypass this error??

The code relevant to the specific issue, creating a MIME message and then creating the according Message as needed:

```
@Path("/sendmessage/{to}/{from}/{subject}/{body}/{userID}")
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response sendMessage(
            @PathParam("to")String to, 
            @PathParam("from") String from, 
            @PathParam("subject") String subject, 
            @PathParam("body") String body,
            @PathParam("userID") String userID)
    {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage =null;
                Message message = null;

                mimeMessage =createEmail(to, from, subject, body);
                message = createMessageWithEmail(mimeMessage);
                gmail.users().messages().send(userID,message).execute();
resp = Response.status(200).entity(message.toPrettyString()).build();

return resp;
}

public static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String bodyText){

          Properties props = new Properties();
          String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", "******");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

          MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
          try{
            InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);

            email.setFrom(fromAddress);
            email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setText(bodyText);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, ********);
            transport.sendMessage(email, email.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e){
               LOGGER.error("Class: "+className+", Method: "+methodName+", "+e.getMessage());

           }
            return email;
      }

 public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            email.writeTo(baos);
        } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Class: "+className+", Method: "+methodName+", "+e.getMessage());
        }
        String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
        return message;
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow API SICOA! Could you show us your relevant code where you try to send the mail?

Comment: Is the user id missing or invalid?

Comment: It was really a stupid issue, from my part, "userID" is useless and was confused with "from" attribute. Remove it, make it "from" and it works alrght. Thank you all for the help and answers

Answer (score 2):

Pass empty string or "me" as the userId in the Gmail API call:

`gmail.users().messages().send("", message).execute();`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore as of 2018 (even though the out-dated documentation says that it still does).

Answer (score 2):

Generally this type of error occurs when authenticated email address and from email address miss match occurs.

So, if you are using client library then pass "me" or empty string while executing as shown in below

> gmail.users().messages().send("me", message).execute();

if you are using rest api then use

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/**me**/messages

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
public static boolean sendEmail(String subject,String to,String content, MultipartFile file,String filenameName) throws Exception{

        try{
            final String username = "***@gmail.com";
            final String password = "***";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");// For gmail Only U can change as per requirement
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //Different port for different email provider 
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            }   
            });
            session.setDebug(true);

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setHeader("Content-Type","text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            if(file!=null){
            //-Multipart Message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            // Create the message part 
                BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                messageBodyPart.setText(content);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);//Text Part Add
            // Part two is attachment
                messageBodyPart= new MimeBodyPart() ;
                ByteArrayDataSource source=new ByteArrayDataSource(file.getBytes(),"application/octet-stream");
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            //Send the complete message parts
                message.setContent(multipart);
            }
            else
                message.setText(content);
            //message.setText(content);
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir, i ll try this on monday and leave the feedback